# `XSetWMNormalHints` and `XSetWMSizeHints`

Tags: c++, c, x11, xlib

I'm confused with `XSetWMNormalHints` and `XSetWMSizeHints`. I want to set my window non-resizable, and a call to `XSetWMNormalHints` does it properly. But if I call `XSetWMSizeHints` instead, nothing really happens; the window is still resizable. How are the 2 functions used for my purpose, and what exactly does `XSetWMSizeHints` do? I've read the documentation multiple times, but I'm still confused, so asking a question here.

```
sh = XAllocSizeHints();
sh->flags = PMinSize | PMaxSize;
sh->min_width = sh->max_width = 100;
sh->min_height = sh->max_height = 100;
XSetWMNormalHints(d, w, sh);
//XSetWMSizeHints(d, w, sh, PMinSize | PMaxSize);
XFree(sh);
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is almost 4 years old, but perhaps this will clarify for others with similar questions.

Calling XSetWMSizeHints with a WM_NORMAL_HINTS property does the same thing as XSetWMNormalHints. The problem with the call to XSetWMSizeHints is that "PminSize | PMaxSize" is a value instead of a property. Here is the code modified to use XSetWMSizeHints with a property.

```
#include <X11/Xatom.h>  // XA_WM_NORMAL_HINTS
...
sh = XAllocSizeHints();
sh->flags = PMinSize | PMaxSize;
sh->min_width = sh->max_width = 100;
sh->min_height = sh->max_height = 100;
//XSetWMNormalHints(d, w, sh);
XSetWMSizeHints(d, w, sh, XA_WM_NORMAL_HINTS);
XFree(sh);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your answer, so that it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xsetwmnormalhints):

> The XSetWMNormalHints function replaces the size hints for the **WM_NORMAL_HINTS property** on the specified window. If the property does not already exist, XSetWMNormalHints sets the size hints for the WM_NORMAL_HINTS property on the specified window. The property is stored with a type of WM_SIZE_HINTS and a format of 32.

while

> The XSetWMSizeHints function replaces the size hints for the **specified property** on the named window. If the specified property does not already exist, XSetWMSizeHints sets the size hints for the specified property on the named window. The property is stored with a type of WM_SIZE_HINTS and a format of 32. To set a window's normal size hints, you can use the XSetWMNormalHints function.

and at the beginning, it shows

```
void XSetWMSizeHints(Display *display, Window w, XSizeHints *hints, Atom property);
```

In your commented-out fragment, it does not use a *property* (does not appear to work). X11 Atoms (see [Xlib Programming Manual: Properties and Atoms](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/properties-and-atoms.html)) are identifiers *like* a C pointer (but *not* actually an address), while `PMinSize | PMaxSize` is something entirely different: a value with specific bits set.  The compiler accepted it because both are unsigned values, but at runtime that value probably does not match any Atom identifier.

`XSetWMNormalHints` is the more useful of the functions because it updates the property which you normally would use: `WM_NORMAL_HINTS`.  The `XSetWMSizeHints` is more general — allowing you to use any property — but you probably do not need the generality.

Comment: I passed `PMinSize | PMaxSize` as the `property` argument in the commented out line. What did I do wrong?